# List of "object" all type - Java

Tags: java, list, object

I have problem, I don't know how to write header of method.

Example:

```
public List<Object> getSubList(List<Object> l, int bot, int top){
      return l.subList(bot, top);
}
```

I want call method, but I don't know what type of list will be on input (String, Integer, or some other object].

I get error:

**`Imcopatible code: List<User> cannot be converted to List<Object>`**

Comment: See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397/java-generics-what-is-pecs).

Comment: how are trying to call this method

Answer (score 0):

`List<User> cannot be converted to List<Object>` , you can't pass `List<User>` to this method.